# Install a yum package using an array list for its version number in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am installing this pip module below, what I want to do is pass in a list into it. So the two numbers that are in the list are installed, like how I have shown.

I know I can just have 2 of the same package name under yum_packages and pass in 3 & 2, but I just wanted to know if I can pass it in somehow as an array.

```yaml
yum_packages:
- python{{ python_version[0,1] }}-pip.noarch

python_version: 
- 3 
- 2
```

Currently, this I get this error:

> The tasks includes an option with an undefined variable" list object has no element(0,1)

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve this, you will have to dynamically expand your variable, using the module [`set_fact`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/set_fact_module.html). And you will also need to use a [`loop`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#loops).

Given the the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    yum_packages:
      - curl   ## Just some example packages to demonstrate
      - vim    ## that the pip packages are added to the list
    python_version: 
      - 3 
      - 2 

  tasks:
    - set_fact: 
        yum_packages: "{{ yum_packages + ['python' ~ item ~ '-pip.noarch'] }}"
      loop: "{{ python_version }}"

    - debug:
        var: yum_packages
```

This yields the recap:

```
PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] ***************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=3)
ok: [localhost] => (item=2)

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  yum_packages:
  - curl
  - vim
  - python3-pip.noarch
  - python2-pip.noarch

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```